# What will git do after a merge from master to a branch?

Tags: git

Imagine there are two branches out of the `master` branch on Git. Let's call them `feature-1` and `feature-2`. Now, someone committed some some code on both branches. The `feature-1` branch was merged into the `master` branch. Now, someone who did not know git very well, merged the `master` branch into the `feature-2` branch to get the code. If new commits would appear on the master branch, and someone else would decide to rebase `feature-2` branch: what would happen to the commit history?

Comment: Have you tried it? One of the strengths of git is that since nothing requires an external server, you can easily create a test scenario locally and test things.

Comment: Also, I assume that by "rebase feature-2 branch" you mean "rebase feature-2 branch on top of master", is my assumption correct?

Comment: To answer your question for the simple case where no conflict or anything is happening, feature-2 would be rebased and retain the commits originally added to it, *except* the merge commit that merged master into it.

Comment: Also, I question your phrasing here with "someone who did not know git very well", this sort of implies that what they did was wrong, which at least in my opinion, is not, can you clarify why you used that phrase?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - not me, but we have this mess in a project.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  to clarify why I used the phrase "someone who did not know git very well": in git flow you should rebase your feature branch to the master/development/main branch and after your work you should merge your feature branch to the master/development/main branch. It totally messes your workflow up.

Comment: The answer provided here seems to conclude with "Which is fine", which you accepted, so I am pretty sure you and I are not talking about the same thing. If the workflow, including a rebase, *is fine*, then how can it *totally mess up your workflow*?

Comment: I asked specifically about the git history so the answer is good as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's illustrate it.

> Imagine there are two branches out of the master branch on Git. Let's call them feature-1 and feature-2. Now, someone committed some some code on both branches.

```
      C - D [feature-1]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      E - F [feature-2]
```

> The feature-1 branch was merged into the master branch

```
      C - D [feature-1]
     /     \
A - B ------ G [master]
     \
      E - F [feature-2]
```

> Now, someone who did not know git very well, merged the master branch into the feature-2 branch to get the code.

```
      C - D [feature-1]
     /     \
A - B ------ G [master]
     \        \
      E - F --- H [feature-2]
```

> If new commits would appear on the master branch, and someone else would decide to rebase feature-2 branch: what would happen to the commit history?

Assuming they rebase onto master...

```
      C - D [feature-1]
     /     \
A - B ------ G [master]
              \
               E1 - F1 [feature-2]
```

Which is fine.